# SQlite Python3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Уважаемые коллеги!
Создаю простую таблицу. И просто хочу вывести значение нужного слово. Например: по имени. Почему то по ключевому слову не получается искать.Только цифры ищет.

```py
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('employeers3.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

create_table = '''
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dannie (
       Familiya VARCHAR,
       Imya VARCHAR,
       Vozrast VARCHAR,
       Salary_USD VARCHAR,
       Position VARCHAR,
       Status VARCHAR
       )
'''
cursor.execute(create_table)

select_data = 'SELECT * FROM dannie WHERE Imya==Sergey'  ## почему то по ключевому слову не получается искать.Только цифры ищет. 
print(cursor.execute(select_data).fetchall())

insert = '''

     #INSERT INTO dannie (Familiya, Imya, Vozrast, Salary_USD, Position, Status)
     #VALUES ('Melnikov', 'Sergey', '45', '20000', 'General Director', 'Manager')
         
'''
cursor.execute(insert)


connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: `select_data = 'SELECT * FROM dannie WHERE Imya = ?'` ... `print(cursor.execute(select_data, 'Some name').fetchall())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вы только что создали новую таблицу и уже хотите читать из нее — но *она пока пустая.*
   Сначала нужно сделать `cursor.execute(insert)`, и только после этого `print(cursor.execute(select_data).fetchall())`
2. SQL не Питон, для сравнения используется не `==`, а только один `=`.
3. Строки должны быть в кавычках или апострофах (как в Питоне), значит имя **Sergey** нужно писать например как `"Sergey"` - в команде `INSERT INTO` вы это сделали, но в команде `SELECT` нет.
   (Числа пишутся без кавычек / апострофов — поэтому ваш вздох «Только цифры ищет.»)

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!

Comment: @Handsome_777, не стоит.:-)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй

```
select_data = 'SELECT * FROM dannie WHERE Imya="Sergey"'
```

Comment: aaaa))) Блин. Оказывается именно двух скобочный нужно ставить. Спасибо большое!